# source ~/.bash_profile error

Tags: bash

I am trying to fix the bash profile but it constantly says:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
/Users/KirSo/.bash_profile:160: command not found: bind
\[\e]2;\u@\h\a[\[\e[37;44;1m\]\t\[\e[0m\]]\[\033[0;31m\] (master) \[\e[32m\]\W\[\e[0m\]\n\[\e[0;31m\]\[\e[0;49;34m\]//\[\033[0;31m\] ♥ \[\e[0m\]
```

checked the line 160 which says:

```
 bind "set completion-ignore-case on"
```

Although with adjust the line, restarting the terminal it still drops the same error.

Comment: What shell is this with? Not actually `bash` presumably.

Comment: Need a MCVE -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- in any event. I suppose it could conceivably contain `disable bind` in one of the 159 lines prior, or there could be a hidden character in that line, but in order for us to be able to diagnose any of these cases the question would need to be updated with instructions someone else can use to produce the same behavior.

Comment: its actually iTerm + zsh on MacOS, but the error started appearing after playing around with installing and re-installing rvm

Comment: Did you found a workaround to this? I'm using zsh and stuck on same issue.

Comment: did you fixed this? I'm running into same issue

Answer (score -2):

Considering the path inside the question, You are probably running CygWin or something similar. Check the $PATH variable and Your env variables. You might have accidently changed the paths in which bash is looking for binaries (such as /bin). Also, on some versions of Linux (dont know about CygWin, sorry :<), there are other bash config files, namely `~/.bashrc` `/etc/bash.bashrc` `/etc/profile`. The names may vary, depending on the distribution and implementation. Check If those contain code that overrides Your $PATH variable.

Comment: Doesn't look at all like cygwin to me. Where do you get that impression? cygwin uses `/home`; `/Users` is more of a MacOS-ism.

Comment: Also, `bind` is a builtin, not an external binary, so PATH is irrelevant. (Almost the only way for a shell builtin to not be present is for the user to not actually be running the shell they claim to be, hence Etan's probably-correct diagnosis -- of the user running a different shell than they claim to be -- in the comments). See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html

Comment: its actually iTerm + zsh but I wasn't getting the error before, it actually started appearing after playing around with rvm. But thanks!

Comment: @KirSo you fixed it?